# Setting UILabel text from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have a question. I need setting text value into a UILabel from NSDictionary.

My code to set text into UILabel is:

```
Refunds *current = [refunds_view objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.sol_number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",current.company];
```

where Current is
Refunds.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


 @interface Refunds : NSObject

-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;

 @property (assign) NSNumber *refunds_id;
 @property (assign) NSNumber *request_number;
 @property (strong) NSString *policy_code;
 @property (strong) NSString *company;

@end
```

Refunds.m

```
 #import "Refunds.h"

 @implementation Refunds 

 @synthesize refunds_id;
 @synthesize request_number;
 @synthesize policy_code;
 @synthesize company;
 -(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data{
  self = [super init];
  if(self){
    NSLog(@"initWithJSONData method called ");


   refunds_id =  [data valueForKey:@"id"];
   request_number = [data valueForKey:@"request_number"];
   policy_code = [data valueForKey:@"policy_code"];
   company = [data valueForKey:@"company"];
  }
  return self;
  }
@end
```

when I try to set value into UILAbel no occurs the error But the value doesn't show complete, only show (

```
NSLog(@"%@",[current company]);

//This is the value of [current company]
2014-06-26 10:32:13.917 Benefits[7178:70b] (
Benefits
)

cell.sol_number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", current.company];
```

Any idea for this.

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: there is no date property are find in your Refunds class....

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I need set value into de UILabel. The value I need setting is [current company];  @Pfitz

Comment: send me nslog of current

Comment: Hi @SuhailKala this is NSLog(@"Current%@",current);                                        `Current <Refunds: 0x8bdcc60>
2014-06-26 14:01:06.657 Benefits[668:70b] Current <Refunds: 0x8bc3ca0>
2014-06-26 14:01:06.661 Benefits[668:70b] Current <Refunds: 0x8bd1590>
2014-06-26 14:01:06.663 Benefits[668:70b] Current <Refunds: 0x8b75a00>
2014-06-26 14:01:06.666 Benefits[668:70b] Current <Refunds: 0x8bc6690>`

Comment: Your current should be one refund object(ur nslog shows 4 objects) , those contain refunds_id, request_number, policy_code and company.An d all of these should contain some values.

Comment: Yes @SuhailKala all components in current content a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to use company value rather then "date" value..just like it

```
cell.sol_number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",current.company];
```

Comment: Yes but when display the list I can see only this character **(** the value of `[current company]` is `//This is the value of [current company]
2014-06-26 10:32:13.917 Benefits[7178:70b] (
Benefits
)`

Comment: Hi @Rohit yes I need set value on my UILabel from NSDictionary and when set this value only see this character **(** and print the NSLog(@"%@",[current company]) and the result is`//This is the value of [current company]
2014-06-26 10:32:13.917 Benefits[7178:70b] (
Benefits
)`

Comment: can you adjust width of uilable... i think u make it bigger try it